# Bash export and use variable with quotes and space in script

Tags: linux, bash, scripting, escaping

I'm trying to pass many jvm parameters to one variable and export it and call in other script, but space nad double quotes in parameter beat me. ("/05 abcdef")

My code:

```
#!/bin/bash
NORMAL_VARIABLE=-DNORMAL.NormalText=normal124
PROBLEMATIC_VARIABLE='-DPROBLEM.ProblematicText="/05 abcdef"'
SUM="$NORMAL_VARIABLE $PROBLEMATIC_VARIABLE"
export SUM
```

Target script:

```
java $SUM -jar "ApacheJMeter.jar" "$@"
```

Actual output in debug mode:

```
+ NORMAL_VARIABLE=-DNORMAL.NormalText=normal124
+ PROBLEMATIC_VARIABLE='-DPROBLEM.ProblematicText="/05 abcdef"'
+ SUM='-DNORMAL.NormalText=normal124 -DPROBLEM.ProblematicText="/05 abcdef"'
+ export SUM
+ java -DNORMAL.NormalText=normal124 '-DPROBLEM.ProblematicText="/05' 'abcdef"' -jar ApacheJMeter.jar
Error: Could not find or load main class abcdef"
```

Anyone have an idea how to solve it?

I want to get:

```
java -DNORMAL.NormalText=normal124 -DPROBLEM.ProblematicText="/05 abcdef" -jar ApacheJMeter.jar
```

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Is it a path /05 abcdef ? Or a file named abcdef in 05 directory etc. Because I could see in error message it tells could not find class abcdef, let me know on same

Comment: Hi! "/05 abcdef" is a value of parameter.
Problems is witch invoke java:

`java -DNORMAL.NormalText=normal124 '-DPROBLEM.ProblematicText="/05' 'abcdef"' -jar ApacheJMeter.jar`

instead of:

`java -DNORMAL.NormalText=normal124 -DPROBLEM.ProblematicText="/05 abcdef" -jar ApacheJMeter.jar`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using bash, you can use arrays.

```
#!/bin/bash
NORMAL_VARIABLE=-DNORMAL.NormalText=normal124
PROBLEMATIC_VARIABLE=-DPROBLEM.ProblematicText="/05 abcdef"
SUM=($NORMAL_VARIABLE "$PROBLEMATIC_VARIABLE")
```

And then

```
java "${SUM[@]}" -jar "ApacheJMeter.jar" "$@"
```

Comment: What is the benefit of the array for `PROBLEMATIC_VARIABLE`? Seems like it would work the same if it were a string in single quotes.

Comment: @TomFenech: True, fixed.

Comment: I think the single quotes are needed, otherwise the double quotes would be syntactical.

Comment: @choroba your version when i run bash -x test.sh 
java -DNORMAL.NormalText=normal124 '-DPROBLEM.ProblematicText=/05 abcdef' -jar ApacheJMeter.jar  How to get rid of ' ?

Comment: @PatrykDadas: Why? You need them, otherwise `abcdef` would be a different parameter.

Comment: @choroba sorry, I did not write correctly.  I need this in -DPROBLEM.ProblematicText="/05 abcdef" style. /05 abcdef in double quotes after equal sign without apostrophe

Comment: So populate the variable accordingly: PROBLEMATIC_VARIABLE='-DPROBLEM.ProblematicText="/05 abcdef"'

Comment: With your answer and last comment it looks like that: 
`java -DNORMAL.NormalText=normal124 '-DPROBLEM.ProblematicText="/05 abcdef"' -jar ApacheJMeter.jar` and is not correct  - apostrophes :(

Comment: @PatrykDadas: The apostrophes are shown in debug mode, they are not part of the real code. Try to run it.